# How to close modals one by one in react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have deep paths in my app. Some of them may be the same. For example, like in twitter you can open some profile -> some post -> some profile -> some post... Then you click "back" and you are going back closing modals one by one.

I tried closing modals by `dismissModal('SomeScreen')`. It's working if I have: profile -> post. But it's not working when there is the same modal twice in the path like: profile -> post -> profile (dismissModal is not closing last one profile).

How I can implement it with `react-native-navigation`?

Code that I used for opening modals:

```
const openContactProfileScreen = async () => {
  await Navigation.showModal({
    stack: {
      id: 'ContactProfileScreen',
      children: [{
        component: {
          name: 'ContactProfileScreen',
          options: { topBar: { visible: false }, bottomTabs: { visible: false } }
        }
      }],
    }
  });
}
```

Closing:

```
Navigation.dismissModal('ContactProfileScreen');
```

packages:

```
"react-native": "^0.59.9",
"react-native-navigation": "^2.22.3",
```

Comment: Please, send your code that handles this. Your question is so general.

Comment: The code is added.